# Is it clear why some non humans look human while others look like their true species?

Tags: log-horizon

In *Log Horizon*, most of the mainchars are half elf, elf, etc. but look like humans. On the other hand, there are players who have animal ears, etc.

Is it explained anywhere why some non humans look humanlike, and others, not?

Comment: I feel like there's some misunderstanding here. It's not an arbitrary decision by the author.  That's just how some fantasy races work. Elves and half-elves look very humanlike in most settings aside from the pointy ears and a tendency to frail, dainty body types. Dwarves are just short and stout people, sometimes with pointy ears too. If you are asking about characters that are full-on furries and others only have animal ears, well, that's because they are completely different races. That's just how it works in the setting.

Comment: @paulnamida that would be an answer then imho as it is just a misinterpretation of what I saw compared to what they TRIED to show there